# What would cause attribute routing to not work when adding it to an existing MVC 5 web app?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-web-api-routing

I added the Web API nuget and the StartUp WebApiConfig code that calls MapHttpAttributeRoutes via Global.asax, but none of the attribute routes are working.

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    SqlServerTypes.Utilities.LoadNativeAssemblies(Server.MapPath("~/bin"));

    MvcHandler.DisableMvcResponseHeader = true;

    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
    GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
    FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
    RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
}
```

Here is the packages installed.

```
<packages>
  <package id="EntityFramework" version="6.1.1" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core" version="2.0.1" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework" version="2.0.1" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin" version="2.0.1" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc" version="5.1.2" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Razor" version="3.1.2" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi" version="5.1.2" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client" version="5.1.2" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core" version="5.1.2" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Owin" version="5.1.2" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost" version="5.1.2" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages" version="3.1.2" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages.Data" version="3.1.2" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages.WebData" version="3.1.2" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Data.Edm" version="5.6.1" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Data.OData" version="5.6.1" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Data.Services.Client" version="5.6.1" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="Microsoft.SqlServer.Types" version="11.0.1" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure" version="1.0.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ConfigurationManager" version="2.0.3" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="6.0.3" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="Owin" version="1.0" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="RestSharp" version="104.4.0" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="SharpZipLib" version="0.86.0" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="System.Spatial" version="5.6.1" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="WindowsAzure.Storage" version="4.0.1" targetFramework="net451" />
</packages>
```

Controller code

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
[RoutePrefix("admin/api/v/{vid}/photos")]
public class PhotosController : ApiController
{
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [Route("test", Name="Test")]
    [HttpGet]
    public IHttpActionResult Test(string vid)
    {
        return Ok();
    }
}
```

Comment: Which package did you add? What is the exact name of it?

Comment: Updated with list of packages

Comment: Can we see what your controller and route attribute look like?

Comment: That is not for Web API 2.

Comment: Updated with controller code

Comment: That looks pretty reasonable. Does it work with a URL of `localhost:<port>/admin/api/v/somestring/photos/test`?

Answer (score 2):

I figured out what was going on, I had two Api controllers with the same name. It looks as if Web Api attribute routing will not differentiate actions and controllers with namespace constraint like MVC does. I simply prepended Admin to the control class name and everything seems to work now.